# ListView Filter not working after fetching data from datasnap server

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have an application made in Delphi Seattle, and i migrated to Delphi Tokyo. But my searches in ListView are no longer working properly.
On a first use, it works correctly, i filter a record and edit it. I send the data to a datasnap server and fetch all records again to refresh the listview. But if I try to search again, it no longer finds the record, however browsing the listview I can find the record.

Apparently all records that are not appearing on the screen when I reload the data are not being filtered. If I manually navigate to the record and perform the search, then it works.

My Code to retrieve data from datasnap and show on listview:

```
  DadosSocio := F_ClientModule.ServerMethods1Client.GetSocio(0);
  Assert(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListCount(DadosSocio) = 1);

  mem_Socios.Close;
  mem_Socios.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(DadosSocio, 0));
  mem_Socios.Open;

  lvSocios.ScrollTo(0);
  lvSocios.ScrollViewPos := 0;
```

I use this code to clean the filter:

```
  for I := 0 to lvSocios.Controls.Count-1 do
  Begin
    if lvSocios.Controls[I].ClassType = TSearchBox then
    begin
      TSearchBox(lvSocios.Controls[I]).Text := '';
    end;
  End;
```

I tried to use this code to clean the filter, but it returns the error `Argument out of Range`:

```
lvSocios.Items.Filter := nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following code:

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to ListView.Controls.Count-1 do
  Begin
    if ListView.Controls[I].ClassType = TSearchBox then
    begin
      TSearchBox(ListView.Controls[I]).Text := '';
    end;
  End;

  ListView.Items.Filter := nil;
```